# Is "... object is not iterable" A Misleading Error For "x in y"?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

Consider the following two classes:

```
class Foo0(object):                                                 
    pass

class Foo1(object):
    def __contains__(self, _):
        return False
```

Neither of them is iterable, as can be observed by trying `for i in Foo1(): pass`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "stuff.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i in Foo1(): pass
TypeError: 'Foo1' object is not iterable
```

Conversely, `3 in Foo1()` is valid (as `Foo1` has `__contains__`), whereas `3 in Foo0()` is not:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stuff.py", line 9, in <module>
    3 in Foo0()
TypeError: argument of type 'Foo0' is not iterable
```

---

I find the error misleading. The point is not that `Foo0` is not iterable - after all `Foo1` is not iterable too, so that's not the inherent reason. Moreover, as @niemmi and @tobias_k correctly note below, if a class does not support `__contains__`, `__iter__` is used as a fallback, which is the direct cause for this error. However this makes things worse, as a user might try to solve this error by implementing `__iter__`, which is a very inefficient means of implementing `__contains__`.

Why was this chosen as the error, then?

Answer (score 7):

If the object doesn't have [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method Python automatically tries to iterate over it to see if it can find the element. Since `Foo0` isn't an iterable you will see the error.

**UPDATE**: [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) explains this in bit more detail:

> For user-defined classes which define the **contains**() method, x in y is true if and only if y.**contains**(x) is true.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define **contains**() but do define **iter**(), x in y is true if some value z with x == z is produced while iterating over y. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines **getitem**(), x in y is true if and only if there is a non-negative integer index i such that x == y[i], and all lower integer indices do not raise IndexError exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if in raised that exception).

Comment: Thanks, @niemmi, that is my understanding too. However, it explains *how* this happens, not if that is the intended rationale of the language designers. Good answer, though.

Comment: The error message should arguably explain the root cause, not how the fallback also failed.